# Add anchor to links using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I'm new to javascript.
Need to remove any existing anchors (eg: #page33) add other anchor (eg: #page1) to all links in a list dynamically (client side) with javascript or jquery:

Initial html (from server):

```
<ul id="lang_menu">
    <li><a href="home.php?lang=eng#page33">English</a></li>
    <li><a href="home.php?lang=tam#page33">Tamil</a></li>
    <li><a href="home.php?lang=sin#page33">Sinhala</a></li>
</ul>
```

this should behave like (replace #page33 with #page1 at client side):

```
<ul id="lang_menu">
    <li><a href="home.php?lang=eng#page1">English</a></li>
    <li><a href="home.php?lang=tam#page1">Tamil</a></li>
    <li><a href="home.php?lang=sin#page1">Sinhala</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is where I need this [Developing Website](http://www.lrh-hospital.health.gov.lk)

Please help me. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Um... why? Can't you just put them in the source?

Comment: anchor is client side ajax page request... This is where I need this: www.lrh-hospital.health.gov.lk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way:-

```
$(function () {
    $('#lang_menu li a').attr('href', function (_, oldHref) {
        return oldHref + "#page1";
    });
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ejyAD/)

For your updated question you can try something like this:

using regex to replace the #part from the url.

```
$(function () {
    $('#lang_menu li a').attr('href', function (_, oldHref) {
        oldHref =  oldHref.replace(/\#(.*)/g, "#page1");
         if(oldHref.indexOf('#') == -1)
            oldHref += "#page1";
        return oldHref;
    });
});
```

#### [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/cRZ5h/)

Comment: Thaks, it works but how can i remove any existing anchors and insert new anchor? as after few clinks it was something like "home.php?lang=eng#page1#page3#page1#page2#page2".

Comment: I did not understand why are you appending on click? Can you share a fiddle?

Comment: also i found less simple way to remove anchor: return oldHref.split("#")[0] + "#page1";

Answer (score 3):

If you are dealing with a lot of DOM elements its less expensive to add the anchor lazily.

```
jQuery("a").bind("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.location = jQuery(this).attr("href") + "#page1";
});
```

Comment: Ew. What happens if I try to middle-click it?